# D3 the years on the x-axis

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am having trouble creating x-axis that includes years and shows the number of arrests for each year.

I have stored my data into arrays.

For example: var arrests = [100,200,300,400] and var years = [2000,2001,2002,2003]

I would like to create a bar chart which includes the arrests on the y-axis and the correstponding years on the x-axis.

In the code below years = [1988,1989..until....2018] and number_of... = [1000,200...].

Both are arrays and have the same size.

```
var barWidth = 35;
var barOffset = 5;

var margin = 30;
var width = 1160;
var height = 200;

var data = number_of_arrest_per_year;

var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain([new Date(1988),new Date(2018])
    .range([0,width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,d3.max(number_of_arrest_per_year)+500])
    .range([height,0]);

var chart = d3.select("#chart");

chart.attr("width",width + 2*margin)
    .attr("height",height + 2*margin)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + 80 + "," + margin + ")")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width",20)
    .attr("height",function(d) { return height - y(d); })
    .attr("x",function(d,i) { return i *(barWidth + barOffset); })
    .attr("y",function(d) { return y(d); });

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(31)

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(5);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 80 + "," + (height+margin) + ")")
    .attr("class","axis")
    .call(xAxis);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 80 + "," + margin + ")")
    .attr("class","axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Thank you very much.

I have updated my code:

1.

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(years)
    .range([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.08)
```

2.

```
 .attr("width",x.bandwidth())
```

Comment: There are several issues with this code: 1. don't use two arrays for the data, but an array of objects. 2. Don't hardcode the bar width, use a band scale. 3 don't use `new Date`, just get the extent of the data. 4. break your `chart` selection. 5. don't use the index to position the rects, just use the scale.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado do you know how to adjust the distance between ticks ?

Comment: Just use a band scale. Have in mind that, from a dataviz perspective, using a bar chart for a time series is not the best option.